# Pick the maximum n values based on a condition in R for each group

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, dataset, slice

I would like to pick the 3 maximum events per year per center so 3 events if I have 1 year, 6 events if I have 2 years and so on. I have already computed the years for each center and sorted for the maximum. I would like something like slice(1:aha) but it does not seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Could you provide your data not in a photo, but in a code form? You can use `dput(yourdataframe)` to edit your question. Then you will get a much faster answer!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! You can have a glimse of the dataset by:center <- c("5580","5580","5580","5580","5580","5580","5580","5580","5580","5580","5855","5855","5855","5855")
max <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26,76,98,98,45,8,8,12,4,6)
years <- c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6,6,6,6,6,6,3,3,3,3)

df <- data.frame(center, max,years). Looking forward for you reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
  df <- tibble::tibble(
    center = c(
      "5580", "5580", "5580", "5580", "5580", "5580",
      "5580", "5580", "5580", "5580",
      "5855", "5855", "5855", "5855"
    ),
    max = c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26, 76, 98, 98, 45, 8, 8, 12, 4, 6),
    years = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3)
  )



# get group names  
df <-  df %>% group_by(years, center) 
df %>%
  group_split() %>%
  set_names(interaction(group_keys(df))) %>%
  purrr::map(~ .x %>%
               arrange(desc(max)) %>%
               slice(1:unique(years))) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thanks but I still miss sth, I would like 6 events for centre 5580 and 3 events for 5855 (as the years indicate - so the number of years are the number of events I want to sample). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: I think that it will work but I get an error :Error: Invalid index: field name 'maptype' not found. I have both libraries installed.

Comment: try `purrr::map()`

Comment: Actually I have one more error: If I try to run it to more data then I get the error:names()` must be the same length as x.I think it is because multiple centers have the same years.

Comment: Does `group_split(years, center)` help? I edited it to include list names, maybe that will help to identify the problem if the group_split does not solve it.

Comment: I get: Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default:(

Comment: did you try the code I edited in my answer? I had a small typo there, sorry

Comment: Yes - unfortunately still the same error.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I cannot reproduce your error. In my most recent edit I added the pipe operator `%>%` after `set_names` because I forget it. If I do not add it, I also get the same error message.